# How to String.Format the day of the month in c#?

Tags: .net, datetime, formatting

DateTime's formatting has some overlap between it'a standard date and time formatting strings and some of it's custom format specifier by them selves. As a result, when I evalate this expression:

```
string.Format(">{0:d}< >{0: d}<", DateTime.Now)
```

and get this result:

> `>8/3/2009< > 3<`

My question is: *How do I get String.Format to output just the day of the month (using the* `d` *format) without any surrounding spaces?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `"{0:%d}`": [reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#UsingSingleSpecifiers)

Answer (score 2):

I keep this page in my favorites...

http://blog.stevex.net/index.php/string-formatting-in-csharp/

Saves me all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DateTime.Now.Day.ToString()
```

Comment: Simple solution, but likely this is part of a larger `String.Format()`, in which case I would personally prefer using `{0:%d}`.

Answer (score 0):

DateTime.Now.ToString("dd");

Comment: That give the day of the week: e.i. "wed"

Comment: I changed it again. It works... This was  really comic :) Me making mistakes and you pointing them out.